# Is there any C++ API available to know the OS description?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I am working on tools that will be used on the multiple OSes and platforms. These tools will provide the details of the OS on which it is running, like 32-bit or 64-bit OS, exact version of Linux, Solaris, or other OS.

One way I am thinking is of using the "uname -a" command to extract the OS information on a Linux/Unix-based OS. Please suggest me that if it is efficient to call the command from the program.

Is there any API available or is there any workaround that I can implement?

Note that I also do need to check for OS information on the Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply wrap the OS detection with #define and each time call the ideal function so as to return a meaningful string in every case?

Some examples of system function to get information about the current OS (such as the running version):

- In Windows the function is:
  [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- FreeBSD (and unixes I guess): [uname](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uname&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html)

Comment: Because you have to know all the OSs in advance in order to write the #defines.

Comment: we can write OS info for OSes inside #define. But still we need some api to get OS information inside #define.

Comment: Well of course you know all the OSes in advance, you're compiling for each one of them!

Windows : GetVersionEx
BSD : uname(3) - #include <sys/utsname.h>

No need to spawn a process. ;)

Comment: In that case, why call the function to determine the OS you already know? I was assuming at least some of the binaries would be cross platform, or the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: A cross platform binary in C++? The goal is in my opinion to have some sort of console get what os the binary is running on. Let's say you have a grid of computers and want to know what os is running on each one of them. That's the sort of problem you want to address. You want to know the OS and the version, hence you modify for each platform.

Comment: Cross platform in sense of running on various Linux flavours, various Windows flavours etc.

Comment: In which case the above approach works very well. One define for Windows, one define for Linux, one for BSD, one for solaris... Maybe you can even unify some of the nixes.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard Library provides no way of doing this, so you are at the mercy of operating system specific features. And even then, there is no general method, as utilities like "uname" are not supported on Windows and will give differently formatted results on different UNIX flavours.

Comment: yeah, Neil you have the right concern but we can cover major OSes like linux, solaris, AIX and windows and can put all other OSes in undefined kind of category.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to sysinfo() call (from `sys/systeminfo.h` on Unix).

Also regarding "uname -a" efficiency, it depends where are you going to use it. In normal circumstances (if your application is not time/CPU  critical) performance of "uname -a" should be acceptable.

There is also a function, "uname()", present in the `sys/systeminfo.h`  file, which may help you.

Comment: Is there any similar api for windows?

Comment: Well i don't think , same functions are there on windows but you can try  "GetVersionEx()"  windows api

Answer (score 0):

I would think that `uname -a` would be a good way, but only for *nixes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. But you can apply fingerprinting techniques to find out the target OS.

These are generally used to guess remote machine OS. You can look at [Nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) also. It does various types of fingerprintings.

Comment: can you provide some links for it? It would be really helpful.

Comment: nmap is opensource tool.You can download from net but will take some effort to figure out how its done. 
You can try searching fingerprinting techniques on net. There are lot of resources available. However you have to do some research on it.